# Why is this syntax not working in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I'm using Python 2.7.5 and this format is not working. As far as I remember it works on my other computer which also has 2.7

```
train_data.ix[:,1:-1]
```

The error I get is:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

If I use `train_data[:,1:-1]` then the error is:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What's exactly your goal? What types are train_data and train_data.ix?

Comment: actually i'm trying understand somebody else's code where the exact line was:
 all_data = numpy.vstack((train_data.ix[:,1:-1], test_data.ix[:,1:-1]))
in the end I want to select particular columns from the dataset

Comment: It works for objects of type ``numpy.ndarray``, not common lists.

Comment: I just added `numpy` tag.

Comment: This looks like AI or Machine learning code, and I think only numpy, scipy and other libraries that use numpy or numpy like arrays support the `[:,:,:]` syntax. See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html

Comment: The extended slice syntax is exceptional, in that it was added to the grammar specifically for use by `numpy`, but not otherwise used by the core Python language. It is not supported by built-in types like `list` or `dict`.

Answer (score 3):

Lists and NumPy arrays do not have an `ix` method:

```
In [8]: import numpy as np
In [10]: x = np.array([])

In [11]: x.ix
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

But Pandas Series and DataFrames do have an `ix` method:

```
In [16]: import pandas as pd

In [17]: y = pd.Series([1,2])

In [18]: y.ix[0]
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: y.ix[1]
Out[19]: 2
```

If `train_data` is a Pandas DataFrame, then `train_data.ix[:,1:-1]`
selects all rows from the second to next-to-last columns. The `:` indicates all rows, the `1:-1` indicates the second to next-to-last columns.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for python slice notation is list:

```
list[start:end:step]
```

If there are any commas in the slice notation it will give you the tuple error.

Answer (score 0):

if you use

```
 list1=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
    >>> list1[:1:-1]
    [7, 6, 5, 4, 3]
```

and if you want to reverse the list, you can use,

```
>>> list1[::-1]
[7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The first error says that `list` object doesn't have attribute `ix` (and it doesn't have, in fact):

```
>>> [].ix
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ix'
```

In the second piece of code you are trying to use comma in the slice. According to this [document](http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) you can't do it with python's lists. AFAIK [you can do it](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) with some `numpy` structures, so you need to convert your list to one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The direct answer to your question is that it is not working because your `train_data` is a list. It appears that the `train_data` in the code you are trying to understand was a Pandas DataFrame object due to the `.ix` property you are using.